# frame number not appear in beamer

Tags: beamer, miktex2.9

I have the following code, the frame number does not appear. I'm using Windows 10 and MikTex 2.9 and this problem occur. I tried the same code using Mac and MikTex 2.8, no problem at all.  Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I had update the package in MikTex console yet this issue persist.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{John Smith}
\title{Sample}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
\date{} 
%\subject{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]`:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\author{John Smith}
\title{Sample}
\date{} 


\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you don't like to see the footline on the title page, you can write:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

[image]